# Can't invoke *method=* type methods in instance_eval

Tags: ruby

Consider the following code:

```
class Student
  attr_accessor :age, :gender, :school

  def explicit_school_setter
    @school = "Some School"
  end
end

bob = Student.new

bob.age = 16
bob.gender = :male

bob.instance_eval { school = :bvb } # ? Why is this not invoking the setter?

bob.age # => 16
bob.gender # => :male
bob.school # => nil

bob.instance_eval { explicit_school_setter }

bob.school # => "Some School"

bob.school = "Another School"

bob.school # => "Another School"
```

Why is the setter not working in the `instance_eval` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a local variable when you call `school = :bvb`. Change this to `self.school = :bvb` and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

D @school instead of only school inside the block as below

```
bob.instance_eval { @school = :bvb }
```